# Running URL Requests in Parallel with Flask

Tags: python, google-cloud-functions, python-asyncio, aiohttp

asyncio is still relatively new for me.

I am starting with the basics - simple HTTP hello world - just making approximately 40 parallel GET requests and fetching the first 400 characters of the HTTP responses using Flask ("parallel" function is invoked by request).

It is running on python 3.7.

The Traceback is showing errors I don't understand. Which "Constructor parameter should be str" is this referring to? How should I proceed?

This is the entire code of the app:

```
import aiohttp
import asyncio
import json

async def fetch(session, url):
    async with session.get(url) as response:
        return await response.text()

async def main():
    global urls
    tasks = []
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        for url in urls:
            tasks.append(fetch(session, url))
        htmls = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
        returnstring = ""
        for html in htmls:
            returnstring += html + ","
            print(html[:400])
        return returnstring


def parallel(request):
    global urls
    urls = []
    request_json = request.get_json()
    if request_json and 'urls' in request_json:
        urls = request_json['urls']
        print(urls)

    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    return loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

The Traceback is showing errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/functions/worker.py", line 346, in run_http_function
    result = _function_handler.invoke_user_function(flask.request)
  File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/functions/worker.py", line 217, in invoke_user_function
    return call_user_function(request_or_event)
  File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/functions/worker.py", line 210, in call_user_function
    return self._user_function(request_or_event)
  File "/user_code/main.py", line 57, in parallel
    return loop.run_until_complete(main())
  File "/opt/python3.7/lib/python3.7/asyncio/base_events.py", line 573, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "/user_code/main.py", line 15, in main
    htmls = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
  File "/user_code/main.py", line 6, in fetch
    async with session.get(url) as response:
  File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 1012, in __aenter__
    self._resp = await self._coro
  File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 380, in _request
    url = URL(str_or_url)
  File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/yarl/__init__.py", line 149, in __new__
    raise TypeError("Constructor parameter should be str")
TypeError: Constructor parameter should be str
```

Comment: What does your `print(urls)` show? Maybe you see what's going on if you add another print to somewhere in `for url in urls: tasks.append(fetch(session, url)`. You end up calling `session.get(url)` somehow so that `URL(str_or_url)` has something else than a string. Globals can be a bad idea, I don't know off-hand how it goes with that parallel thing there. Have used google app things and python async stuff with flask recently otherwise.

Comment: this code works for me - without Flask and Google Cloud - so maybe get file from error message `...yarl/__init__.py` and check what is in line 149. If you can you could add `print()` n this file to see what value makes problem.

Comment: BTW: I used urls directly in list `urls` without `request.get_json()` and I sent it without global `run_until_complete(main(urls))`

Comment: I tested: if I use something different then string (ie. tuple/list) in `session.get( (url, something) )` then I get your error. So you have wrong data in `urls`

Comment: @furas yes after adding another print() for the urls variable, i found that is exactly the problem. how can i give you credit for the answer?

Comment: @antont thanks for the advice. that fixed it. how can i give you credit for the answer?

Comment: @furas do you have the code for this: "BTW: I used urls directly in list urls without request.get_json() and I sent it without global run_until_complete(main(urls))" ? I didn't know how to do it without globals so i'm curious to see

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tested: if I use something different then string (ie. tuple/list) in

```
session.get( (url, something) )
```

then I get your error. So you have wrong data in urls.

---

Code which I used to test it:

```
import aiohttp
import asyncio

async def fetch(session, url):
    async with session.get(url) as response:
        return await response.text()

async def main(urls):
    tasks = []
    results = []
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        for url in urls:
            tasks.append(fetch(session, url))
        results = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
    return results

def parallel(urls):
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    results = loop.run_until_complete(main(urls))
    return results

# --- main ---

urls = [
    #('https://stackoverflow.com/', 1), # TypeError: Constructor parameter should be str
    'https://stackoverflow.com/',
    'https://httpbin.org/',
    'http://toscrape.com/',
]

result = parallel(urls)

for item in result:
    print(item[:300])
    print('-----')
```

---

I don't know what you get `request_json['urls']` but you should get only urls

```
 urls = request_json['urls']
 urls = [ ??? for x in urls] # in place `???` use code which get only url from `x`
```